# Does Shakespeare use the word "whence" incorrectly?

Tags: grammaticality, shakespeare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “from whence” correct? Or should it be “whence”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/is-from-whence-correct-or-should-it-be-whence)

From the [Shakespeare's Sonnet XLVIII](http://www.shakespeares-sonnets.com/sonnet/48),

> ... 
>  From **whence** at pleasure thou mayst come and part;
>         
>  And even thence thou wilt be stol'n I fear,
>         
>  For truth proves thievish for a prize so dear.

Isn't the definition of *whence* is "from where" or "from what place" which when converted from the phrase above will be "From from where at pleasure..."? Does Shakespeare use the word *whence* incorrectly?

Comment: I am closing this as a dupe (which it is), but frankly, any question titled "Do [sic] Shakespeare use X incorrectly" is rhetorical at best, and better closed as NARQ.

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary has 720 citations attesting *from whence*, so I think it would be rather hard on Shakespeare to suggest he has made a mistake. As far as current usage is concerned, *whence* is probably best avoided altogether, other than for special effect.